# c# ping class throws exception in monodevelop

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, ping

I have the below simple ping method in my program.

```
    internal static bool Pinger(string host_to_ping = null)
    {
        bool network_available = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

        int timeout_per_host_millis = 1000;

        if (network_available)
        {
            Ping p = new Ping();

            try
            {
                PingReply r = p.Send(host_to_ping, timeout_per_host_millis);

                if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    return true;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But when `Ping p = new Ping();` Instantiated it throws...

> An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Monodevelop 4.2.2
Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: Refer `InnerException` for more information.

Comment: InnerException {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.CheckLinuxCapabilities () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 } System.NullReferenceException

Comment: as @Jonathan said, ping needs root privilege, you can run ping from your console only because it is suid

Comment: @Karata it is true that ping has SUID set, however I get the same error when trying to invoke `new Ping()` even when running monodevelop as root.

Comment: @Karata, Is there a workaround for MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 16.04 so we can invoke new Ping() even when running MonoDevelop as sudo or root? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue a couple of days ago and the simplest fix/workaround is to run monodevelop as root.

For example open a terminal and type:

```
sudo monodevelop
```

With monodevelop now open as root. Open your project and compile as normal and you should see it execute correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, any other option?

Comment: @jambel I'm having the same issue; Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @jambel, Is there a workaround for MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 16.04 so we can invoke new Ping() even when running MonoDevelop as sudo or root? Thank you.